# Problems with buttons after Wordpress update/ Plugin update

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I don't have so much experience. I can't use anymore these 3 buttons (the problem appeared after plugins update / wordpress update)

Initially i could click those 3 buttons and open like the first button to the left and the image would change. None of these happens now.

Could someone help me fix this ?

edit:
www.daisytech.ro 
sorry i forgot to mention the website

edit 2:
i have a backup on my computer , you can see how should work (i could use this back-up but i've translated the website and i would lose another part of work

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw35J.jpg)

Comment: how are we going to fix if you will only show the image? share the code or create a fiddle

Comment: there is an error through your js check the console

Comment: @SorinVeștemean please let us know that the slides are dynamic or static??

Comment: @SorinVeștemean i've added an answer to explain what you changed to make it work. Please change the accepted answer to reflect the solution you chose so that other users will find it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slider is using master-slider plugin.

The `master.js` file in the theme is using jQuery.tools.tabs, but `jQuery.tools` is `undefined`. `$.tools` returns an object so i guess the problem was the scope of `$`

The fix was wrapping the entire contents of the file in a

```
(function(jQuery){
    // the contents of the file
})($);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Really appreciate!